# Laravel - how to group by pivot table column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, eloquent-relationship

I have a many to many relationship with one extra column in pivot table i.e `module_id`, i want to eager load the relationship data `groupBy('module_id')`. I tried couple of thing that didn't work, I successfully managed to get the desired structure but  not through the eager loading (right way), i directly called the pivot table model queried the table. The problem is i cannot query pivot table directly becuase i have implemented the repository pattern.

This is how i queries the pivot directly.

```
$selectedGroups = RoleGroup::select('role_id', 'module_id', 'group_id')->where('role_id', $role->id)->get()->groupBy('module_id');
```

**Migration:**

```
Schema::create('role_groups', function (Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('module_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('group_id');
    $table->timestamps();
                
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**Role Model:**

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'role_groups')->withPivot('module_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Group Model:**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_groups')->withPivot('module_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Desired Structre:**

> The keys are module_id and the values inside are group_id

```
{
    "1": [
        1
    ],
    "2": [
        1
    ],
    "3": [
        1
    ],
    "4": [
        1
    ],
    "5": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
```

**What i got:**

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "role_id": 1,
            "module_id": 1,
            "group_id": 1
        },
        {
            "role_id": 1,
            "module_id": 1,
            "group_id": 3
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "role_id": 1,
            "module_id": 2,
            "group_id": 1
        },
        {
            "role_id": 1,
            "module_id": 2,
            "group_id": 3
        }
    ],
    "3": [
        {
            "role_id": 1,
            "module_id": 3,
            "group_id": 1
        }
    ],
    "5": [
        {
            "role_id": 1,
            "module_id": 5,
            "group_id": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve this by grouping by multiple columns. i.e:

```php
RoleGroup::query()
    ->select("module_id", "group_id")
    ->where("role_id", $role->id)
    ->groupBy("module_id", "group_id")
    ->get()
    ->reduce(
        function (array $carry, Model $item) {
            $carry[$item->module_id][] = $item->group_id;
            return $carry;
        }
        , []);
```

References:
[`reduce()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-reduce)
[`groupBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#grouping)